# Reduce memory allocation and increase speed in Julia code

Tags: performance, optimization, julia, logistic-regression

I am trying to run multiple regressions for all possible combinations of selected variables. My code is running but it takes a long time and the memory allocation seems very big. Is there a way to optimize this:

```
using DataFrames
using Statistics
using GLM
using Combinatorics
using Distributions


### read the data
reg_dat = DataFrame(
    sample = wsample([1,2],[0.8,0.2], 1000000),y_var = rand(1000000),
    ind = rand(1000000), brak = rand(1000000), times = rand(1000000),
    tiny = rand(1000000), regr = rand(1000000), breaker = 1 .- rand(1000000),
    x_var = 10*(1 .- rand(1000000)), kink = rand(1000000), h_var = rand(1000000),
    ind_x = rand(1000000), brak_x = 1 .- rand(1000000), times_x = 1 .- rand(1000000),
    tiny_x = 1 .- rand(1000000), regr_x = rand(1000000), breaker_x = rand(1000000),
    t_var = rand(1000000), x_var_x = rand(1000000), kink_x = rand(1000000),
    units = rand((1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,15,78,76,10,23,45,54,87,98), 1000000),
    trent = 1:1000000, rz = rand(string.(1:25), 1000000)
)

# find all possible combinations of the independent variables
function combinat(names::Array{String,1},indices::Array{Int64,1},N::Int64)::Vector{Array{String,1}}
    
    cols = Vector{String}()
    coms = Vector{Array{String}}()
    
    for i in indices
         push!(cols, names[i]::String)
    end
    for j in 1:N
        append!(coms, collect(combinations(cols,j))::Array{Array{String,1},1})
    end
    return coms
end

combs = combinat(names(reg_dat),[3:20...], length([3:20...]))

### Find all unique units
units = unique(reg_dat.units)


## Convert combinations to regression formulas
function convert_to_formula(vals::Array{Array{String,1},1})::Array{FormulaTerm{Term,R} where R,1}
    
    forms = Array{FormulaTerm{Term,R} where R,1}()
    
    for i in vals
        new_i = [i;["rz","trent"]]
        symbs = Array{Symbol,1}()
        for j in new_i
            push!(symbs, Symbol(j))
        end
        push!(forms, Term(:y_var) ~ sum(term.(symbs)))
    end
    
    return forms
end

# Run regressions for each combination of units and combs
function logit_run(data::DataFrame, units::Array{Int64,1}, ind_vars::Array{Array{String,1},1})::Array{Tuple{Int64,String,Float64},1}
    
    forms = convert_to_formula(ind_vars)
    out = Array{Tuple{Int64,String,Float64},1}()
    
    for i in units
        data_train = data[(data.sample .== 1) .& (data.units .== i),:]
        data_test = data[(data.sample .== 2) .& (data.units .== i),:]
        for j in forms
            try
                logit = glm(j, data_train, Binomial(), LogitLink(), contrasts = Dict(:rz => DummyCoding()))

                devs = data_test.y_var - predict(logit,data_test)
                push!(out, (i, string(j), sqrt(mean(devs .* devs))))
            catch
                push!(out, (i, string(j), NaN))
            end
        end
    end
    return out
end
```

Now when I run:

```
@time logit_run(reg_dat, units, combs[1:10])

> 18.413586 seconds (26.24 M allocations: 10.644 GiB, 10.50% gc time)

170-element Array{Tuple{Int64,String,Float64},1}:
 (1, "y_var ~ ind + rz + trent", 0.2880341157225821)
 (1, "y_var ~ brak + rz + trent", 0.2880411138604235)
 (1, "y_var ~ times + rz + trent", 0.2880380466963764)
 (1, "y_var ~ tiny + rz + trent", 0.2880396984065766)
 (1, "y_var ~ regr + rz + trent", 0.2880343939542883)
 (1, "y_var ~ breaker + rz + trent", 0.2880393689495619)
 (1, "y_var ~ x_var + rz + trent", 0.288038968246708)
 (1, "y_var ~ kink + rz + trent", 0.288043185030096)
 (1, "y_var ~ h_var + rz + trent", 0.28804607747341865)
 (1, "y_var ~ ind_x + rz + trent", 0.2880387457490556)
 (98, "y_var ~ ind + rz + trent", 0.29044425999770246)
 (98, "y_var ~ brak + rz + trent", 0.2904354957341227)
 (98, "y_var ~ times + rz + trent", 0.2904391507891304)
```

The memory allocation is high and it is not as fast as I would want it. I will be running millions of iterations with this and will want 170 elements to be faster than this. Any help is appreciated.

Update:

Using a low level API did not quite work for me so I found a python implementation of the logistic regression and wrote it in Julia

```
### Adding an intercept of ones
reg_dat[!, :Intercept] = ones(nrow(reg_dat))

### Creating dummies for the rz variable
for i in unique(reg_dat.rz)[2:end]
    reg_dat[!, Symbol(i)] = ifelse.(reg_dat[!, :rz] .== i, 1, 0)
end

# find all possible combinations
function combinat(indices::Array{Int64,1},N::Int64)::Vector{Array{Int64,1}}
    
    coms = Vector{Array{Int64}}()
    
    for j in 1:N
        append!(coms, collect(combinations(indices,j)))
    end
    return coms
end
combins = combinat([3:20...], length([3:20...]))
unit_s = unique(reg_dat.units)

### Now the logistic regression function from scratch
function log_reod(unit_s::Array{Int64,1}, combos::Array{Array{Int64,1},1}, cols::Array{String,1}, mydata::DataFrame, iterations::Int64)
    
    out = Array{Tuple{Int64,String,Float64},1}()

    Threads.@threads for j in combos::Array{Array{Int64,1},1}
        Threads.@threads for i in unit_s::Array{Int64,1}
            try 
                train = mydata[(mydata.sample .== 1) .& (mydata.units .== i),:]
                test = mydata[(mydata.sample .== 2) .& (mydata.units .== i),:]

                X = Matrix(train[!, [24; j;[22,25:48...]]])[:,:]
                y = train[!, :y_var]

                X_test = Matrix(test[!, [24; j;[22,25:48...]]])[:,:]
                y_test = test[!, :y_var]

                w = zeros(size(X)[2])
                y_bar = mean(y)

                w_init = log(y_bar/(1-y_bar))

                converged = false
                nll_sequence = Array{Float64,1}(undef,iterations)

                ab = Array{Tuple{Float64, Bool}, 1}(undef,iterations)
                Threads.@threads for i in 1:iterations
                    h = X*w
                    p = 1 ./ (1 .+ exp.(-h))
                    p_adj = p
                    p_adj[p_adj .== 1.0] .= 0.99999999
                    nll = -(1 - y'log.(1 .- p_adj)) + y'log.(p_adj)
                    nll_sequence[i] = nll

                    if i .> 1
                        if !converged & (abs(nll_sequence[end]-nll_sequence[end-1]) < 0.000001)
                            converged = true
                        else
                            converged = false
                        end
                    else
                        converged = false
                    end

                    s = p .* (1 .- p)
                    S = Diagonal(s)

                    arb_small = ones(length(s)) .* 0.000001
                    arb_small[s .!= 0] = ((y.-p)./s)[s .!= 0]

                    z = h + arb_small

                    w = ((inv(X'*S*X)*X')*S)*z

                    pred = exp.(X_test*w) ./ (1 .+ exp.(X_test*w))

                    rmse = sqrt(mean((y_test - pred) .* (y_test - pred)))

                    ab[i] = (rmse, converged)      
                end
                global ab_fin = ab[findfirst(getfield.(ab,2))-1][1]
            catch
                global ab_fin = NaN
            end

            push!(out, (i, join(cols[j],","), ab_fin))
        end
    end
    
    return out
end
```

This seems to work. However, memory allocation is worse and not as fast as the implementation with the GLM (high level) API. Why is this the case?

```
@time log_reod(unit_s, combins[1:10],names(reg_dat), reg_dat, 15)

171.060764 seconds (5.88 M allocations: 91.736 GiB, 12.45% gc time)
170-element Array{Tuple{Int64,String,Float64},1}:
 (4, "ind", 0.29000435564005556)
 (15, "ind", 0.28887795028663027)
 (8, "ind", 0.286764063267709)
 (98, "ind", 0.28941319680023303)
 (76, "ind", 0.2898017575615879)
 (3, "ind", 0.2910086150956134)
 (45, "ind", 0.288856696122843)
 (9, "ind", 0.287618950665158)
 (1, "ind", 0.2884813713274216)
 (2, "ind", 0.28729283992016885)
 (7, "ind", 0.28700362633959264)
 (6, "ind", 0.2873866890697135)
 (10, "ind", 0.28889513223197577)
 ⋮
 (3, "ind_x", 0.29102070956343595)
 (45, "ind_x", 0.28884184457957934)
 (9, "ind_x", 0.2876167225404162)
 (1, "ind_x", 0.2884805471334929)
 (2, "ind_x", 0.2873338122136366)
 (7, "ind_x", 0.2870078816051725)
 (6, "ind_x", 0.28739698518229273)
 (10, "ind_x", 0.28891515579773225)
 (23, "ind_x", 0.2898286130508298)
 (78, "ind_x", 0.2890331733804241)
 (54, "ind_x", 0.28855221319296853)
 (87, "ind_x", 0.2875034656519413)
```

Comment: Do not use high-level API from a table, but low level API using matrices. Then do the subsetting using `view`s (both on rows and on columns). This way you will greatly reduce memory allocations at the cost that you have to do the "bookkeeping" yourself.

Comment: Can you please show me how in my code?

Comment: your code is complex and it would require a complete rewrite - I can give a MWE in an answer to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have misdirected you - sorry for this.
GLM.jl does not support views. Still you can reduce the time if you use matrices directly, but not much unfortunately.

Data preparation

```
df = DataFrame(rand(10^6, 10))
df.y = sum.(eachrow(df)) .+ 10 .* randn(10^6) .< 5

function some_models(df)
    [glm(@formula(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10), df, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     glm(@formula(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9), df, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     glm(@formula(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x10), df, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     glm(@formula(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x9+x10), df, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     glm(@formula(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x8+x9+x10), df, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     glm(@formula(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x7+x8+x9+x10), df, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     glm(@formula(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10), df, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     glm(@formula(y~x1+x2+x3+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10), df, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     glm(@formula(y~x1+x2+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10), df, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     glm(@formula(y~x1+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10), df, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     glm(@formula(y~x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10), df, Binomial(), LogitLink())]
end

function some_models2(df)
    X = [ones(nrow(df)) Matrix(df[!, 1:end-1])]
    y = df.y
    [fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X, y, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X[:, Not(11)], y, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X[:, Not(10)], y, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X[:, Not(9)], y, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X[:, Not(8)], y, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X[:, Not(7)], y, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X[:, Not(6)], y, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X[:, Not(5)], y, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X[:, Not(4)], y, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X[:, Not(3)], y, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X[:, Not(2)], y, Binomial(), LogitLink()),
     fit(GeneralizedLinearModel, X[:, Not(1)], y, Binomial(), LogitLink())
    ]
end
```

Benchmarking:

```
julia> some_models(df); # first run

julia> @time some_models(df); # second run
  8.955404 seconds (10.72 k allocations: 4.713 GiB, 5.36% gc time)

julia> some_models2(df); # first run

julia> @time some_models2(df); # second run
  8.598572 seconds (1.20 k allocations: 3.412 GiB, 8.65% gc time)
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me something to explore. Just wondering, Is there a regression package that supports views so I can use to run the models?

Comment: I have checked this by changing the GLM.jl source codes. But it seems that internal functions that make it fast actually are faster if it is a `Matrix` (so a continuous block of memory, i.e. e.g. more cache friendly) so allowing a `view` actually made the code run slower. Do you have a reference of logistic regression estimation package that runs faster than GLM.jl on CPU?

Comment: not really. I don't think I have a reference of logistic regression that does that. But I have updated my question with a function that implements logistic regression from scratch. It's slower. Can you help?